# Bloc builder not printing current state in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, cubit, flutter-cubit

I am working on a flutter project where i am calling an Api using bloc provider and emiting a state if i got the output.When i printed the output in cubit its working and after emiting that output i cant get it in bloc builder, even the state is also not printing in bloc builder.
my api fetch code is as below

```
Map<String, dynamic> fields = {'upload_id': widget.content.id};
          ApiModel apiData = (ApiModel(
            fields: fields,
            token: userToken == null ? userDataGlobal['data'].token : userToken,
          ));

          if (widget.content.isSeries) {
            BlocProvider.of<SeasonCountCubit>(context).getSeasonCount(apiData);
            BlocBuilder<SeasonCountCubit, SeasonCountState>(
                builder: (context, state) {
              print('state is $state');
              if (state is SeasonCountLoaded) {
                print('season Cout is ${(state as SeasonCountLoaded).data}');
                setState(() {
                 int seasonCount = (state as SeasonCountLoaded).data;
                });
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            });
          }
```

and my cubit is as follows

```
part 'season_count_state.dart';

class SeasonCountCubit extends Cubit<SeasonCountState> {
  final Repository repository;
  SeasonCountCubit({this.repository}) : super(SeasonCountInitial());

  getSeasonCount(ApiModel fields) {
    repository.getSeasonCount(fields).then((datas) {
       emit(SeasonCountLoading());
      print('seson count in cubit $datas');
      seasonCount = datas;
      emit(SeasonCountLoaded(data: datas));
    });
  }
}
```

```
part of 'season_count_cubit.dart';

@immutable
abstract class SeasonCountState {}

class SeasonCountInitial extends SeasonCountState {}

class SeasonCountLoading extends SeasonCountState {}

class SeasonCountLoaded extends SeasonCountState {
  final int data;
  SeasonCountLoaded({this.data});
}
```

Anyone please help me with this..

Comment: Can you please share the code where your BlocProvider is created? So the whole widget is missing here. And also why are you using setState?

Comment: i dont know whether if setstate can be used here or not.. that why